# Как по клику запустить php файл из java и получить результат работы php

Tags: php, javascript

При клике не кнопку нужно запустить файл test.php и его результат получить в JS переменную. Как такое организовать друзья, подскажите.

Comment: почитайте про ajax запросы http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=1452

Comment: А лучше про [xhr](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest) на чистом js